# GotoIf hash key pressed at the end of Record command

Tags: asterisk

We ask the caller to record their name then press hash key `#`. If the hash key has been pressed they should move to next step, otherwise go back and ask them to record the name again.

```
exten => s,n(RecordName), Playback(Please Record Your Name After Beeb then press '#')
exten => s,n,Record(recordpath/namefile.wav,60)
exten => s,n,GotoIf ('# isn't pressed')?RecordName)
```

Is there any way to detect if `#` is pressed at the end of `Record` command?

Comment: the close reason "unless they directly involve programming or programming tools" doesn't apply here, because this question directly involves a programming language (asterisk extension scripts are some sort of twisted basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check documentation of Record command.

It clearly say which variables it set on # key.

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show application Record 

  -= Info about application 'Record' =- 

[Synopsis]
Record to a file. 

[Description]
If filename contains '%d', these characters will be replaced with a number
incremented by one each time the file is recorded. Use 'core show file formats'
to see the available formats on your system User can press '#' to terminate
the recording and continue to the next priority. If the user hangs up during
a recording, all data will be lost and the application will terminate.
${RECORDED_FILE}: Will be set to the final filename of the recording.
${RECORD_STATUS}: This is the final status of the command
    DTMF:A terminating DTMF was received ('#' or '*', depending upon
    option 't')
    SILENCE:The maximum silence occurred in the recording.
    SKIP:The line was not yet answered and the 's' option was specified.
    TIMEOUT:The maximum length was reached.
    HANGUP:The channel was hung up.
    ERROR:An unrecoverable error occurred, which resulted in a WARNING
    to the logs.

[Syntax]
Record(filename.format[,silence[,maxduration[,options]]])

[Arguments]
format
    Is the format of the file type to be recorded (wav, gsm, etc).
silence
    Is the number of seconds of silence to allow before returning.
maxduration
    Is the maximum recording duration in seconds. If missing or 0 there
    is no maximum.
options
    a: Append to existing recording rather than replacing.

    n: Do not answer, but record anyway if line not yet answered.

    q: quiet (do not play a beep tone).

    s: skip recording if the line is not yet answered.

    t: use alternate '*' terminator key (DTMF) instead of default '#'

    x: Ignore all terminator keys (DTMF) and keep recording until hangup.

    k: Keep recorded file upon hangup.

    y: Terminate recording if *any* DTMF digit is received.


[See Also]
Not available
```

Comment: can I use the value of ${RECORD_STATUS} Directly (i.e,.

 `GotoIf(${RECORD_STATUS}=DTMF?specificCMD)`